# No terminal after installing Ubuntu 16.04 Server Setup

Tags: server

I have installed Ubuntu Server 16.04. 
After installing some packages: `gcc`, `cuda`, `nvidia` drivers. I could not see any terminal login prompt.

The display is stuck on something like this

```
[4.315611] hub 2-4:1.0: USB hub found
```

However, I could log in using ssh from another computer. What should I do to bring back console or gui? My preferred will be to bring back just a text console to log in.

I could reboot pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> on the actual machine prompt. I looked into the dmesg (by ssh) but could not find anything suspicious.

I have also tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and all other Function keys, but nothing happens.